# Laravel: Acessar atributos de relacionamento

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Tenho as tabelas **produtos**, **imagens**, **produtos_imagens**.
 A tabela **produtos_imagens** possui uma chave estrangeira da tabela **produtos** e **imagens**.

Quando vou listar os produtos e os nomes das imagens que estão na tabela **imagens** com o comando abaixo, não consigo:

```
foreach($produtos as $produto) {
   echo $produto->imagens->first()->id;
}
```

Mas funciona se eu acesso assim:

```
foreach($produtos as $produto) {
   echo $produto->imagens->first()['id'];
}
```

Estou acostumado a acessar do primeiro modo as outras relações, mas nessa das imagens me retorna o erro:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Controller

```
$produtos = Produto::get();
```

Model Produto

```
public function imagens()
{
    return $this->HasMany('App\ProdutoImagem');
}
```

Model ProdutoImagem

```
public function imagem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Imagem');
}
```

DD(parte do relations)

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
"imagens" => Collection {#255 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => ProdutoImagem {#260 ▼
      #table: "produtos_imagens"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▶]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "imagem" => Imagem {#269 ▼
          #table: "imagens"
          #fillable: array:2 [▶]
          +timestamps: false
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:3 [▶]
          #original: array:3 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Existe algo no seu Model ´Imagens´ que possa estar convertendo tudo para Array?

Comment: Posta a saída de dd($produto); dentro do looping mesmo

Comment: Alterei o post e coloquei mais informações.

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] Estava dando erro, por que alguns produtos não possuíam imagem. Só não entendi por que quando eu listava com "->" dava erro e com [' '] funcionava.

Comment: A dica que dou é sempre printar a variável similarmente ao que sugeri no coment anterior, somente a variável objeto sem os atributos